# Hardening video download (VideoJS and Laravel 4 / PHP)

Tags: php, laravel-4, video-streaming, html5-video

I'm creating a web app with Laravel 4, and right now i'm in the middle of the video streaming / serving. I'm using VideoJS (i think it's the best and the most customizable solution), but I want to make harder to download videos.

Video serving steps:

1. VideoJS initialized and blocking right click
2. Checking if user is authenticated
3. Starting video serving (using https://gist.github.com/ranacseruet/9826293)

The problem is that if I open the video source i can right-click and save, but I've checked VidToMe where i can do the same thing but only a 2-5MB video is downloaded (first request status is 200 but the rest is 500).

How can i achieve this?

Verifying referrer or something else?

Any other tips to make harder downloading videos?

Thanks!